# List of Users in dropdownlist at adding form

Tags: development

When You adding a new element to the list, how made in adding item drop down list, where can users choise person which adding this thing to the list. I want to person have got a chance to choise person from the dropdownlist. I want dropdownlist at adding form. With name of users, and in order that name schould be.

Comment: Grzegorz, for selecting people SharePoint gives people picker with dialog.. why you insist using Drop down?

Comment: Because, when You searching in search it's very slow, and choise from drop down list schould be faster way.

Comment: And some of persons can choise another perons then. And fast change.

Comment: No, I think drop down will take more time than the default people picker, you can narrow down the people picker by assigning it a group!

Comment: And How assing people in a group ?

Comment: This will not serve the purpose as we want it to be more user friendly. If the user added is not there in the group then it will throw an error and the user will keep guessing about it.
Rather than this we want a list of users that are displayed in a DropDown List and when selected it is added as is added in people picker column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grzegorz,

You can narrow down the People field by assigning it a SharePoint Group...

See below image:
[image]

Here you can provide your SharePoint Group to select people from!